# How to union two incomplete tables in teradata

Tags: sql, join, teradata, union

I need to union two incomplete tables in Teradata. I know there is a function analogous to union in Teradata that does this.

first table:

```
id name
1  John
2  NULL
3  Nick
4  NULL
```

second table:

```
id name
1  John
2  Andrew
3  NULL
4  NULL
```

I need union them to get:

```
id name
1  John
2  Andrew
3  Nick
4  NULL
```

How to do it?

I know this can be done through a normal union\join. But I dont know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it looks like a **join** along with the [coalesce](https://forgetcode.com/teradata/1145-coalesce) function:

```
select a.id,
       coalesce(a.name, b.name) name
from t1 a join t2 b on a.id = b.id
```